# Get image attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the src attribute of an image with the jQuery. In the following code, if I do not wrap image in the `div` or `li` etc., then it works fine, but if I change the HTML mark up, it does not work:

**jQuery:**

```
function setNavi( $c, $i ) {
    var title = $i.attr( 'alt' );
    $('#title').text( title );

    var $prev = ($i.is(':first-child')) ? $c.children().last() : $i.prev();
    var prev_link = $prev.attr('src').split('/large/').join('/small/');
    alert(prev_link);       /* test image src */

    var $next = $i.next();
    var next_link = $next.attr('src').split('/large/').join('/small/');
    alert(next_link);   /* test image src */
}

$(function() {
    $("#carousel").carouFredSel({
        items: 1,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',

        scroll: {
            onBefore: function( data ) {
            setNavi( $(this), data.items.visible );
        }
        },
        onCreate: function( data ) {
            setNavi( $(this), data.items );
        }
    });
});
```

**This works:**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="Alt text" / >
</div>
```

**This does not work:**
If I wrap the image in following html, it does not work:

```
<div id="wrap">
<ul>
        <li>
            <div class="left">
                      <div class="image">
                          <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="Alt text" / >
                       </div>
                 </div>
            <div class="right"><div class="text">some text</div></div>
        </li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: a `div` is not a list, and can't have `li` children, and invalid markup makes for strange results!

Comment: @adeneo sorry, it was just a mistake writing code here. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are using `.next()`.

`.next` will find the `next` element not its all possible `child` you need to use `.find` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how about the previous, that does not use .next and it still doesnt work.

Comment: @user1251698 you can use `.closest()` for that.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't seem to work. In my code above do I need to replace the `.last()` with the `.closest()`? Do I also need to replace the  `.prev()`

Comment: `console.log($c);` and `console.log($i);` and see what DOM its pointing to.

Comment: `$prev.attr(...) is undefined`

Comment: that means $prev is not a DOM obj

Comment: From the console log I can see this:  `Object[ul#wrap]` and  `Object[li]`
Can you kindly give any suggestion on how to fix it?